# Updating a table in Access

Tags: ms-access, ssis, ms-access-2010

Once again I have a question about access. I am translating an Access project into a SSIS project. During the analyiss of the queries I found something like this:

```
update A inner join B on A.Column1 = B.Column1
and A.Column2 = B.Column2
set A.column3 = B.column3
A.column4 = B.column4...
B.column# = B.column#;
```

My question is about the last sentence. What is the purpose of making a setting between the same column of the same table (B.column# = B.column#)?. My job mates have been executing this queries without any problem, but when I tried to translate this into SQL I've got an error message: "... failed with the following error: "The multi-part identifier "B.column# " could not be bound..".

Answer (score 0):

By trying to update a column in Table B you are trying to update 2 tables with a single update statement.  And you can't update multiple tables in one statement in SQL, hence the error.  If you need to update both A and B, you would need to use multiple statements, possibly within a transaction to ensure both statements are treated as a single command.

But as you allude to, it doesn't make sense to update a column in table B with itself.  The only reason I can think you would want to do this, is that there is a trigger that is checking which columns are being updated